# Traçar linhas partir de um ponto e ângulo específico

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou buscando uma forma de traçar uma linha a partir de um ponto e uma angulação (azimute) para depois construir um polígono com a intersecção destas linhas.

```
  base <- tibble::data_frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    x = c(10, 5, 3),
    y = c(5, 10, 4),
    azimute = c(330, 120, 45),
  )
```

No exemplo abaixo, cada `id` tem uma coordenada x/y e um ângulo de visada (azimute, onde 0/360 é norte, 90 é oeste e etc).

As linhas de exemplo foram construídas utilizando trigonometria ('na mão'), mas meu interesse é fazer num SIG (pacote sf ou sp) pois o projeto envolve pontos dentro de um estado brasileiro e a referencia espacial é importante.

[image: exemplo]

O desafio é construir as linhas a partir de cada `id` utilizando os azimutes. o comprimento da linha não tem importância, será um valor grande para garantir que elas se intersectem.

O objetivo final é criar um polígono criado a partir da intersecção dos segmentos.

Answer (score 1):

Como as retar são compostas de duas partes, o desafio é defini-las. Estas duas partes são, o intercepto e a inclinação (que são também as `aes()` requeridas para o `geom_abline()`).

O primeiro passo é conseguir a inclinação com base em um angulo em graus. Para isso podemos calcular a tangente com `tan()`. Merece atenção o fato de que o argumento passado para ela deve estar em radianos.

```
inclinacao <- function(graus) {
  radiano <- x  * pi / 180
  tan(radiano)
}
```

Para definir o intercepto com base nas informações que temos até agora (coordenadas `x` e `y` do ponto e a inclinação da reta), podemos definir a seguinte função:

```
intercepto <- function(x, y, b) {
  y - x * b
}
```

Agora, com este ferramental em mãos, podemos adicionar o intercepto e a inclinação a nossa tabela e depois criar o gráfico.

```
library(tidyverse)

base2 <- base %>% 
  mutate(b = inclinacao(azimute),
         a = intercepto(x, y, b)) 
base2

# A tibble: 3 x 6
     id     x     y azimute      b     a
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10     5     330 -0.577  10.8
2     2     5    10     120 -1.73   18.7
3     3     3     4      45  1.000   1. 

ggplot(base2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = a, slope = b), linetype = 2) +
  geom_label(aes(label = glue::glue("id:{id}\nAz:{azimute}"), 
                 y = y + c(0.5, -0.5, 0.5)))
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2, 11), ylim = c(3, 11))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]